# Que é uma cuca?

Tags: definição

Na música "Ex-Amor", os versos finais são:

> Sempre sonhámos
>   Com o mais eterno amor.
>   Infelizmente,
>   Eu lamento, mas não deu...
>   Nos desgastámos
>   Transformando tudo em dor,
>   Mas mesmo assim
>   Eu acredito que valeu.
>
> Quando a saudade bate forte
>   É envolvente.
>   Eu me possuo
>   E é na sua intenção,
>   Com a minha **cuca**
>   Naqueles momentos quentes
>   Em que se acelerava o meu coração.

O que é uma cuca?

Infelizmente a palavra tem pouco contexto, não a consigo perceber. Talvez seja uma mulher amada - namorada, amante, ou mulher...

[No dicionário](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/cuca) não encontrei nenhuma definição relacionada.

Comment: Na última entrada, 2, vem mulher velha e feia. O Aulete acrescenta rabugenta. Às vezes, entre casais, dá-lhes para usarem estes nomes carinhosos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em **ptBR** "cuca" é uma **gíria** que significa **"cabeça"**, **"mente"**, **"raciocínio"**.  Significa também **um tipo de bolo** ("uma cuca de maçã", e neste caso não é gíria).  Embora a frase "...na sua intenção, com a minha cuca, naqueles momentos quentes..." soe estranho, **o significado certamente é "cabeça", "pensamento"**.  Temos algumas expressões idiomáticas com a palavra "cuca":

- **"fundir a cuca"**
- **"ficar encucado"**
- **"ficar de cuca quente"**
- **"ficar lelé da cuca"**
- **"encher a cuca"**

Os exemplos a seguir falam por si:

- "Ele fundiu a cuca de tanto estudar"
- "A frase que ela usou - você nunca fala o que deveria falar - me deixou encucado. O que será que ela quis dizer?" - "Nâo esquenta a cuca não, cara. Talvez nem ela saiba."
- "Ele fica de cuca quente facilmente, principalmente quando o Benfica perde."
- "Ela parece lelé da cuca. Ficou insistindo para que eu desse um beijo no cachorro.
- "Estou pensando em sair com os amigos e encher a cuca hoje a noite."

Mas se tu estás aprendendo a língua portuguesa, não esqueças: "cuca" é uma gíria e, como tal, seu uso é bem informal.